# black bar above tableview after segue

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

I have an application that has an login-flow. In this login flow you have the possibility to remember your login and password onto your iPhone. When I do this and I restart the app I get a black bar between my tableview and my navigation bar. For mor clarification you see here a screenshot of my storyboard.

[image] 
And you can see a screenshot of the problem over here.

[image]
So when does this happens. When I first start the app and I enter my login and pwd. Everything is OK. But when I save my login credentials on my phone. And restart the app. It skips the login screen and immediately goes to the tabbar. And at that moment the black bar appears.

Does anybody know what the problem can be?

Kind regards

Comment: your credentials are saved but you have no data in the model classes, you have to load that data in models too

Comment: I think that that is not the problem, because the tableview is just filled with dat from arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Dont Skip the login screen, just check if the login is saved then show the add a View (`Loading View` with `UIActivity indicator`) but on the background of that View use to User save credentials to login again. and when you will successfully login then Hide the added `View`. This is surely help you